# Even dimensional real projective spaces cannot be combed

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds, projective-space, spheres

I have to prove that the even-dimensional real projective space cannot be *combed*, i.e. there isn't any non-vanishing smooth vector field.

(I can't use Hopf theorem since those manifolds are not orientable.)

What I think I need to use is that even-dimensional spheres cannot be combed neither.

Somehow, my idea is the prove the statement by contradiction, using the fact that $\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1}$ is obtained from $S^{2n+1}$ identifying antipodal points.

But, I cannot proceed further.

Any help?

Comment: Could you use the projection to pull back a vector field?

Comment: Mhmm that's not clear to me. To map vector fields, I use push-forwards, and to map differential forms, I use pul-backs

Comment: Yes, that's what always works. The other way only works in specific situations. When can you pull back a vector field via a smooth map $f\colon M \to N$?

Comment: I've never heard about it. I don't know how to answer

Comment: Okay, if $F$ is a diffeomorphism @DanielFischer

Comment: But the projection is not injective

Comment: $F$ is a special kind of projection: It is (furthermore) a local diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical map $\pi \colon S^k \to \mathbb{R}P^k$ is a local diffeomorphism. Let $v$ be a vector field on the projective space. On every small enough open $U \subset S^k$ (small enough means it doesn't contain any antipodal points) you can define a smooth vector field $\hat{v}_U$ via the push-forward through the inverse of the projection:

$$\hat{v}_U = \bigl((\pi\lvert_U)^{-1})_{\ast}v.$$

The locally defined fields coincide on the intersections of their domains, hence you get a globally defined smooth vector field $\hat{v}$ on the sphere. Since the differential of $\pi$ is an isomorphism of tangent spaces at each point, $\hat{v}$ has zeros if and only if $v$ has zeros.

Comment: I will rewrite everything under my point of view to see if O've understood

Answer (score 1):

$\pi:S^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Let $v:\mathbb{R}P^{2n}\to T\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ be a non-vanishing smooth vector field.

For every $p\in \mathbb{R}P^{2n}$, let's consider $v_p\in T_p\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ and such that $v_p\ne 0$.

Consider $\pi^{-1}(p)=\{p_1,p_2\}$. Let's choose $p_1$.

Consider $U\subset S^{2n}$ neighborhood of $p_1$ sufficiently small.

We have

$$
\pi_{|U}:S^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}P^{2n}
$$ 
diffeomorphism.

Hence
$$
d(\pi_{|U})^{-1}:T\mathbb{R}P^{2n}\to TS^{2n}_{|U}
$$
is well-defined.

Define $\tilde{v}:=d(\pi_|U)^{-1}v$. $\tilde{v}$ gives the desired contradiction.